# how to insert div/textarea inside html5 shapes like rectangle.?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a HTML5 project in which i have to make text with its boundary. I am using ctx.strokeRect(x,y,width,Height) to draw rectangle. My shape(rectangle) is resizable. I want to insert textarea or div inside rectangle so that on resizing text adjust itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating. Just create a div with the following CSS rule:

```
.mydiv {
    width: Xpx;
    height: Xpx;
    background-color: #COLOUR;
    resize: both;
}
```

Replacing "Xpx" with the amount of pixels for width and height, and "#COLOUR" with an actual hex color code.

Comment: but on resizing my rectangle. div will get focus and rectangle will not reszze until div get focus.

Comment: You want it to resize by itself? With no user interaction?